# Java application wont load images after exporting

Tags: java, eclipse, image

I have problem with eclipse, after i export my application into jar or runnable jar file app doesnt load images.When i run application inside eclipse it runs fine all images loaded properly.I tryed to move my source folder inside default src folder which doesnt helped. Also tryed to import all images one more time,Refreshing project , changing code to getClass().getResource("imgs\someimage.png") , making a new folder and moving everything there,also copy/paste whole classes into another project.Wierd thing is that i have same style in another project and everything work just fine!Bud in this case i cant get it to work.Build path is set perfectly just like project before.And all the images that i need after exporting into jar i see inside it.I use example: labelIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon("imgs\\someimage.png")); for most people getClass().getResource()... fixed the problem  , bud in my case not. Any ideas??Might this be a bug in Eclipse?

Comment: Can you upload some code? Also, picture of your project structure in Eclipse would be helpful.

Comment: http://oi42.tinypic.com/15eteh3.jpg here is screenshot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating `imgs` folder, create package instead (in `src` folder). I.e. `org.imgs`. And then load images as resources:

```
getClass().getResource("/org/imgs/nameOfImage.png")
```

Comment: Making a package fixed the problem! Perfect advice! and fast! :) cant thank you enought!